# Removing large image files from production database

Tags: sql-server, filestream

The database design for a retail organization has several tables with image columns. These account for around 40% of the table size due to their large size.  (Many a DBA issues come from inheriting the existing environment).  This is a production database.  I would like to know of a way to archive the current images from the database. Is there a better way besides FILESTREAM to  store or have access to image files than this?  I am thinking of a column with link to file system where the image is stored.  How does one get to that point? Can someone point me in the right direction